# Disable certain nodes of a tree control

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i have a treeView control with checkboxes:

checkbox LEVEL1

```
  checkbox Child1
  checkbox Child2
```

checkbox LEVEL2

```
  checkbox Child1
```

I shloul not allow checking and unchecking of  Child2 of Level 1 and Child 1 of Level 2?

is that possible in a tree View control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that a TreeNode doesn't have a Enabled state nor any event you can ask. So to emulate the Enabled state you could use the Tag property and save a boolean value there when you create each node.

Then you add an event to the TreeView.BeforeCheck and implement in some kind of this:

```
void TreeView_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var IsReadOnly = e.Node.Tag as bool?;

    if (IsReadOnly != null)
    {
        e.Cancel = IsReadOnly.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, BeforeCheck.  The logic probably doesn't need Tag.

Comment: Indeed doesn't the logic described above need the Tag. But to have it simpler (faster) at each BeforeCheck event i would determine if a node is checkable at creation time of the node and then just check the result at BeforeCheck (if that wouldn't be possible think about another cache solution)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as far as I know. But you can emulate it yourself:

Change the node color to gray:

```
treeControl.Nodes[0].ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

And catch the click event:

```
private void treeControl_AfterCheck(TreeControl tc,
                                            NodeEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Node.ForeColor == Color.Gray)
    e.Node.Checked = !e.Node.Checked;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very good approach. Why depend on the color?

Comment: Well, i guess this an approach that i would follow. Indeed a good suggestion! thanks Carra. 

Salvo, i would not depend on the color ... would be checking another variable! 

Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: It's just the general idea. You can use the node.Tag or a keep a list with disabled nodes.